# `bundler install --deployment` missing `to_yaml`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am not a ruby expert, but I have managed to gather enough information to setup a `Gemfile` and install required Gemfiles.

Lately, however, I've had some problems. For whatever reason, I am now getting this error:

```
> bundle install --deployment
      Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
      troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb:129:in `set_key': undefined method `to_yaml' for {"BUNDLE_FROZEN"=>"1"}:Hash (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb:129:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb:129:in `set_key'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/settings.rb:17:in `[]='
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `__send__'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/bin/bundle:20
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.1/bin/bundle:20
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

I have taken a look at the [recommended link](http://bit.ly/bundler-issues), but the problem remains. My `Gemfile` is quite simple:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'sass'
```

And the accompanying `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    sass (3.2.6)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  sass
```

Why is bundler failing to install?

**Further details**:
Using an older version of bundler (say, 1.2), works just fine. Just not *1.3.1*

I am using ruby 1.8.7, and rubygems 1.8.11.

Comment: What version of ruby and rubygems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same issue and solved it by uninstalling the latest bundler version 1.3.1

```
gem uninstall bundler -v 1.3.1
```

**bundler 1.3.0** should make it pass ;)

edit: no idea why though :|

Answer (score 0):

Any chance the when you installed ruby you didn't have libyaml installed on the system. Ruby requires libyaml for it's standardlib yaml library to function.

Try installing libyaml (look up how to for your particular OS) and then re-installing ruby.

Comment: Hmm... well, I install `libyaml`, uninstalled `bundler`, `rubygems`, and `ruby`, then worked in reverse to install them. Same problem.

Comment: What OS are you on? You may need libyaml-devel or something similar. Are you using RVM?

Comment: Not using `rvm` (I am not very familiar with ruby). Not sure of the OS, as `uname -o` just returns `GNU/Linux`. It's an AWS machine.

Comment: Try going into irb: `irb -r yaml` and running: `Psych.dump("foo")` see if the yaml parser is working and just the to_yaml method is missing for some other reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25557/discussion-between-nt3rp-and-tal)